# AVX2 shuffle data

Tags: assembly, avx2

For example,
ymm1:0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30
ymm2:1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31
change to
↓
ymm3: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
ymm4:16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
Does the AVX2 instruction set have an instruction to meet this requirement?
I looked for the official manual, but couldn't find it. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
Thanks!

I looked for the official manual, but couldn't find it. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: Not as a single instruction, but `vpunpcklwd` is pretty close, giving 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23, then `vpunpckhwd` gives 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31, and you can swap some 128-bit parts around to get what you wanted. But maybe you can work with that slightly different order?

Comment: If you just want to store the results, you can after `vpunpcklwd` and `vpunpckhwd` separately store the lower lanes and  `vextractf128` the upper lanes to memory (this requires no shuffle uops on Intel CPUs, but four instead of two store operations) -- otherwise, it is either two shuffles or one shuffle and two blends. Sometimes it is also possible to load/generate the input data differently.

Answer (score 4):

AVX's use of 128 bit lanes makes this operation surprisingly tedious. It is often easier think about two vectors in the order

```
---------------------
|    A    |    C    |
---------------------

---------------------
|    B    |    D    |
---------------------
```

rather than

```
---------------------
|    A    |    B    |
---------------------

---------------------
|    C    |    D    |
---------------------
```

As suggested in comments, the (AC | BD) combination is given with one `vpunpcklwd` and one `vpunpckhwd`. Going to the (AB | CD) order involves a few more, and more costly operations. They may be particularly costly on platforms that implement AVX with 128 bit vectors, such as Zen1.

In any case, here is a version using [Intel intrinsics](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html). I also recommend searching instructions there rather than in the reference manual or random internet sites.

```cpp
#include <immintrin.h>

void interlace(short* out, const short* in)
{
    /* 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 | 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 */
    __m256i first = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i const*) in);
    /* 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 | 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 */
    __m256i second = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i const*) (in + 16));
    /* 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 | 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 */
    __m256i ac = _mm256_unpacklo_epi16(first, second);
    /* 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 | 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 */
    __m256i bd = _mm256_unpackhi_epi16(first, second);
    /* 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 | 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 */
    __m256i low = _mm256_inserti128_si256(
          ac, _mm256_castsi256_si128(bd), 1);
    /* 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 | 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 */
    __m256i high = _mm256_permute2x128_si256(
        ac, bd, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 3, 0, 1));
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*) out, low);
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*) (out + 16), high);
}
```

The assembly looks like this:

```
        vmovdqu ymm2, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+32]
        vmovdqu ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi]
        vpunpcklwd      ymm1, ymm0, ymm2
        vpunpckhwd      ymm0, ymm0, ymm2
        vinserti128     ymm2, ymm1, xmm0, 0x1
        vperm2i128      ymm1, ymm1, ymm0, 49
        vmovdqu YMMWORD PTR [rdi], ymm2
        vmovdqu YMMWORD PTR [rdi+32], ymm1
        vzeroupper
```

For Zen 1, the `vperm2i128` is very costly (1 per 3 cycles). Two `vextractf128` and two 128 bit stores for the (CD) part may be cheaper. Or replace it with an extract and insert.

```cpp
    __m256i high = _mm256_castps_si256(_mm256_insertf128_ps(
          _mm256_castsi256_ps(bd),
          _mm256_extractf128_ps(_mm256_castsi256_ps(ac), 1),
          0));
```

I don't think this is necessary on more recent architectures. When in doubt, consult [uops.info](https://uops.info/). Note for example how the floating point shuffles may be cheaper than integer shuffles of the same size.

Comment: If you're optimizing for Intel or Zen 2 or later, you'd use `vperm2i128` (1 uop) to grab the high 128-bit half from each of 2 input vectors, instead of emulating it with extract/insert for the 2nd shuffle.  For Zen 1, yes you might want `vextracti128 [rdi+32], ymm1, 1` / `vextracti128 [rdi+32+16], ymm0, 1` or your extract/insert/store.  Or not, since `vextracti128 [mem], ymm0, imm` is 2 uops on Zen 1, same as Intel (no ALU uops for Intel, but doesn't micro-fuse, so it's good for shuffle bottlenecks).  It would be better on Piledriver where 256-bit store is disastrously slow for no good reason.

Comment: Also, https://uops.info/ has more detailed and reliable instruction tables than Agner's, free of copy/paste errors or typos.  Agner Fog's tables sometimes miss instructions, and occasional errors like a 5 instead of 0.5 IIRC.  And not always full detail about memory vs. register versions of instructions, or as detailed port breakdowns for multi-uop instructions.  (Agner's tables are very good, and for years were the best available, but more automated result generation from fully automated testing has done even better.)